# How can I create a program to print the sum of a dictionary

Tags: python

I am writing a Python program that will accomplish the following:

1. loop over all of the items and sum their values.
2. the user needs to input the values into the program.
3. use the split method to break up the string.
4. loop over the input until it has been fully processed.

Phase 1:

```
# Author: Evan Gertis
# Date: 05/11
# input: {'item':value..'item1':value1...}
import logging
import re
dictionary = {} 
# Step 1: process input
input = input()
# Step 2: add key and values from input
# break the input into -> key value
print(input.split())
sum = 0
for k,v in dictionary:
    sum += v
```

Phase 2

```
# Author: Evan Gertis
# Date: 05/11
# input: {'item':value..'item1':value1...}
import logging
import re
from numpy import var
# Instantiate logger and dictionary
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
dictionary = {} 
# Step 1: process input
def getlines():
    while input != 'quit':
        yield input()

# break the input into -> key value
# Step 3: loop through user input
for string in getlines():
    if string != 'quit':
        number, power = string.split()
        logging.debug("%s %s",number,power)
        logging.debug("Adding: %s %s",number,power)
        # Step 2: add key and values from input
        dictionary[power] = number

# Step 4: calculate total value and print the score
sum = 0
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    sum += v
    print("The total number of items: "+sum)
```

How can I process the loop in the input?

Input:

```
12 arrow
42 gold coin
1 rope
6 torch
1 dagger
```

Output:

```
Total number of items 62
```

Comment: you are "adding" strings. you need to convert them to integers (or floats) first. and don't use the name `sum` as a variable because that's a built-in function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a better way of doing what you're doing...

```py
data = {}
while True:
    try:
        string = input()
        if string == 'quit':
            break
        number, item = string.split()
        data[item] = int(number)
    except:
        print('Invalid Input')

print("The total number of items: ", sum(data.values()))
...
The total number of items:  62
```

If your full input is literally just `12 arrow 42 gold coin 1 rope 6 torch 1 dagger` and you don't actually need the dictionary:

```
puts = "12 arrow 42 gold coin 1 rope 6 torch 1 dagger"
sum([int(x) for x in puts.split() if x.isnumeric()])
...
62
```